# Did Hydra and Ten Rings collaborate only in Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015, hydra

In *Ant-Man* when the fight began in Pym Tech between Hydra, Darren Cross, and the Protagonists one of the bad guys had a Ten Rings tattoo on his neck:

[image: Ten Rings]

Some people say he is an ex-Ten Rings member and he is now a member of Hydra. But I doubt that's true. Because all Hydra members say "Hail Hydra". How can someone say Hail Hydra and have the tattoo of another criminal group on his neck? The Hydra boss surely want him to remove the tattoo and mark himself with a Hydra tattoo. Of course, generally, I can't understand the guy for having a Ten Rings tattoo because the tattoo will publicize his affiliation.

So my question is, is this the only collaboration between Hydra and the Ten Rings? Or they have other collabs which I don't know?

Comment: Probably he got hired at *GOONS-Я-US*.

Comment: Hydra is not in its best shape after *The Winter Soldier* and *Age of Ultron*. I don't think that they feel very picky about their recruits.

Comment: If you don't like the assumptions in the question, an answer for why this generic goon has a ten rings tattoo during a period where the organisation is under Xu Wenwu's control would be good.

Comment: *"Because all Hydra members say "Hail Hydra""*, - er, no, they don't.

Comment: "The Hydra boss surely want him to remove the tattoo and mark himself with a Hydra tattoo" — right, the secret criminal organisation that spent decades infiltrating S.H.I.E.L.D. wants to make sure that all its operatives are clearly marked.